# Populate combobox values with another combo values in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have two comboboxs.i want to set second combobox values on the basis of first combobox values on change.like if i three values (1,2,3) for first one and on select 1 i populate second one with values (11,12,13) and same for others.I can do it in php but don't know how to do it in js or jquery.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

**JavaScript**

```
var first = document.getElementById('select-input'),
    second = document.getElementById('second-select-input');

first.onchange = function (e) {
  var val = e.target.value;
  empty(second);
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    addOption(val + '' + (i + 1), second);
  }
};

function empty(select) {
  select.innerHTML = '';
}

function addOption(val, select) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = val;
  option.innerHTML = val;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="select-input">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="second-select-input">
</select>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/bamonoqe/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks for the replay.As for integer values concern it works but how i can set string values like ("this is one","this is seond") ? Hope you can also give some nice solution for this.

Comment: for second combo values will be like `1=>'one this','seond one'`,and for `2=>'UK','US'` etc.Different string values on second combo while first one same values integer.Got point ?

Comment: Please refactor my example and achieve the effect you want.