# Hiding the currently selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am surrently having an issue using JQuery. I have 2 select fields.

```
<select id="cat" name="cat_id">
    <option value="2">Cat 2</option>
    <option value="3">Cat 3</option>
    <option value="4">Cat 4</option>
</select>

<select id="subcat" name="subcat_id">
    <option class="subcats cat_2" value="1">Subcat 1</option>
    <option class="subcats cat_2" value="2">Subcat 2</option>
    <option class="subcats cat_3" value="3">Subcat 3</option>
    <option class="subcats cat_3" value="4">Subcat 4</option>
    <option class="subcats cat_3" value="5">Subcat 5</option>
    <option class="subcats cat_0" value="0">No subcats for this cat</option>
</select>
```

And here is my JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var curval = $("#cat").val();
$(".subcats").hide(0);
$(".cat_"+curval).show(0);

$("#cat").change(function(){

    var cat = $(this).val();
    $(".subcats").removeAttr("selected").hide(0);
    if($(".cat_"+cat).length == 0){$(".cat_0").show(0);}
    else{$(".cat_"+cat).show(0);}
});

</script>
```

Here is the problem. When I change the value of the `cats` select, the options for the `subcats` are changed correctly. However, the currently selected field is still showing (Even if it doesn't correspond to the current cat).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to hide Cat 2 to be hide, if any of the subcat 2 selected? Or you want the whole `id="cat"` to hide?

Comment: @lolka_bolka I think he wants a single combobox to have options based on the value of a different combobox. So, this is a repeated question in that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462390/populate-combobox-values-with-another-combo-values-in-js

Comment: Yes, using hide/show() is not a good choice for select options.  Best to rebuild the list dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code a little bit so on the hange event it can add the selected attribute to the first element in the available options :)

```js
var curval = $("#cat").val();
$(".subcats").hide(0);
$(".cat_" + curval).show(0);

$("#cat").change(function() {

  var cat = $(this).val();
  $(".subcats").removeAttr("selected").hide(0);
  if ($(".cat_" + cat).length == 0) {
    $(".cat_0").attr("selected", "selected").show(0);
  } else {
    $(".cat_" + cat).eq(0).attr("selected", "selected");
    $(".cat_" + cat).show(0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="cat" name="cat_id">
  <option value="2">Cat 2</option>
  <option value="3">Cat 3</option>
  <option value="4">Cat 4</option>
</select>
<select id="subcat" name="subcat_id">
  <option class="subcats cat_2" value="1">Subcat 1</option>
  <option class="subcats cat_2" value="2">Subcat 2</option>
  <option class="subcats cat_3" value="3">Subcat 3</option>
  <option class="subcats cat_3" value="4">Subcat 4</option>
  <option class="subcats cat_3" value="5">Subcat 5</option>
  <option class="subcats cat_0" value="0">No subcats for this cat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Addind the $(".cat_" + cat).eq(0).attr("selected", "selected"); line worked perfectly, I didn't even know this existed. Thanks.